# Billing tier issues with 30 day active user query within bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way using bigquery that I can run this query and not have to use such a huge billing tier? It ranges anywhere from 11 - 20 on the billing tier. Is my only option to crank up the billing tier and let the charges flow?

```
WITH allTables AS (SELECT
  app,
  date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN period = 1  THEN users END) as days_1
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app,
    dates.date as date,
    periods.period as period,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as users
  FROM `table.*` as activity
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC') as date
    FROM `table.*`
    CROSS JOIN
        UNNEST(event_dim) as event) as dates
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT
        period
      FROM (
        SELECT 1 as period
      )
    ) as periods
    WHERE
      dates.date >= TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY, 'UTC')
    AND
      FLOOR(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dates.date, TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), DAY)/periods.period) = 0
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
  )
  GROUP BY 1,2) SELECT
 app as target,
 UNIX_SECONDS(date) as datapoint_time,
 SUM(days_1) as datapoint_value
FROM allTables
WHERE
 date >= TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Day, 'UTC'), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
GROUP BY date,1
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: never give up! what billing tier you get if you run your query for just one day?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I'm pretty sure the billing tier would be less than 4. I can't only run it for one day though, I need to run it for at least 30 days.

Comment: i got it! understood! but you need to think out of the box to get it solved - right? if you will just stick with what you have - you will never get it! anyway - so just approach this formally - can you run it just for 1 or max 2 days - just for the sake of seeing what billing tier it will get to

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Sure thing, give me one moment. The query posted there is also incorrect, the one I should have posted omits the `app_events_*`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant So it turns out I was incorrect, running the updated query gives me a required billing tier of `12`. It is for a single day now.

Comment: one more question  - how many tables yo have in your dataset? you use just `.*` which means all tables - so how many?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant That will all depend on the actual dataset I'm querying but for this one specifically, it's 122 app_events tables and 2 intraday, total 124. Limiting the data using a `table_suffix` is not an option really here unless I could block it into month sections and then loop programatically in my app.