# Does the pricing on high compute queries differ from high byte queries?

Tags: google-bigquery

For example if "m going to run a query that will process 100mb of data but will require billing tier 12 will that be more expensive than a query that requires billing tier 1 but processes 500mb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cost of query execution is `billing bytes` x `billing tier` x $5 per 1 TB

so in your example

```
12 x 100 MB will have cost of of 2.4 times higher than 1 x 500 MB   
just because of simple math -  (12 x 100) / (1 x 500) = 2.4
```

Comment: So if I don't go over 1tb I won't get charged?

Comment: you will be charged! prorated!

Comment: Okay, so for example I just ran a query with billing tier 12. It processed 101MB of data. How much would my charge be for this particular query?

Comment: cost of 500 MB is $5/1024/1024*500=$0.0023841

Comment: cost of 101MB with 12 tier is :  $5/1024/1024*101*12=$0.0057792663574219

Comment: you multiply billing bytes by billing tier and than apply/prorate $5 per 1TB - exactly as I explained in my answer

Comment: sorry - i think i missed the point in your first comment - so yes - `First 1 TB per month is free`

Comment: Yeah, that's cool. Any update on the other issue I was having? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786245/billing-tier-issues-with-30-day-active-user-query-within-bigquery

Comment: you mean another your question ?

Comment: Correct, I've been looking into it and still can't figure it out.

Comment: if you mean - http://stackoverflow.com/q/43786245/5221944 - i will think and follow up if any ideas

Comment: Yeah, I would really appreciate anything at all you figure out. Been struggling on this one for a while.